# pass multiple arguments to the ends_with function

Tags: rust

I can do this without any problems:

```
"hello".ends_with("o"); //true
```

However, I would like to compare the end of the line with several variants:

```
let endings = vec!["o", "a"];

fn check_str(s: &str, e: Vec<&str>) -> bool {
    s.ends_with(e)
}

check_str("some...", endings); //true or false
```

Is it possible to do this without resorting to iterating over an array or vector with `for`?

Comment: `ends_with`  expects [pattern](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/pattern/index.html), you can use slice of chars as pattern `"hello".ends_with(&['o', 'a']); //true`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to do this without resorting to iterating over an array or vector with for?

Depends.

If you're only looking for single characters, then yes: the signature of `str::ends_with` is

```rust
pub fn ends_with<'a, P>(&'a self, pat: P) -> bool where
    P: Pattern<'a>,
    <P as Pattern<'a>>::Searcher: ReverseSearcher<'a>,
```

This means anything which implements `Pattern` works. `Pattern` is an unstable API so you only get what the standard library implements, which is:

- strings of any form -> single substring
- char -> contained in string
- Fn(char) -> bool -> function returns true
- slice of `char` -> any of the chars

The last one would be your "in":

```rust
fn main() {
    let endings = vec!['o', 'a'];
    for s in &["some...", "strings", "ends", "with", "carbonara"] {
        dbg!(s.ends_with(endings.as_slice()));
    }
}
```

If you need something more complex (e.g. multiple actual substrings), then iteration is your only option.

However that doesn't mean you have

> resorting to iterating over an array or vector with for?

Rust has great support for iterators, so you can write something like:

```rust
endings.iter().any(|n| s.ends_with(*n))
```

And this will return true/false depending on `s` ending with any of `endings`'s values.

Comment: One can also use iter `find` instead of `any` to get the char that matched

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to iterate by yourself with `for`, you can use a functional style, but it will iterate internally, however.

```rust
fn check_str(
    s: &str,
    endings: &[&str],
) -> bool {
    endings.iter().any(|e| s.ends_with(e))
}

fn main() {
    let endings = vec!["o", "a"];

    println!("{}", check_str("some...", &endings));
    println!("{}", check_str("hello", &endings));
    println!("{}", check_str("voila", &endings));
}
/*
false
true
true
*/
```